# REST Service with jax-rs : BeanCreationException

Tags: java, web-services, spring, rest, jax-rs

Hello i have a problem with apache cxf and a rest service (with jax-rs, and spring).

I'm trying to publish a rest service : userService

The error is :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1546)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.checkResources(AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.java:315)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:144)
    ... 29 more
25 oct. 2012 16:42:21 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
GRAVE: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1546)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.checkResources(AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.java:315)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:144)
    ... 29 more
```

The web.xml :

```
    <display-name>CXF REST Example</display-name>
<description>CXF REST Example</description>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext-cxf.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The applicationContext-cxf.xml :

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />

<jaxrs:server id="userService" address="/">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="userService" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>
```

The service interface :

```
@Path("v1")
public interface UserService {
    @GET
    @Path("user")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public User getUser();
}
```

The service implementation :

```
@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    public User getUser() {
        User u = new User();
        u.setFirstName("plop");
        u.setLastName("plop");
        u.setEmail("plop@plop.com");
        u.setUuid("1");

        return u;
    }

}
```

Thanks a lot for the help ! This problem kills me !

Comment: just curious, from where this message is coming ? "GRAVE: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé "

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem is here:

```
<jaxrs:server id="userService" address="/">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="userService" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>
```

You're creating a bean named "userService" referencing a bean named "userService". Maybe change the bean name of the jaxrs:server endpoint to something different from "userService"?

Answer (score 1):

In case you are working with Spring Boot go to application.properties or application.yaml set cxf.jaxrs.component-scan=true and then annotate your service implementation class with @Service, this is only a short way to avoid writing xml config files

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<jaxrs:server address="/">
<jaxrs:serviceBeans>
<ref bean="userService" />
</jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>
```

Remove id attribute, bean name should start with lowercase letter.